# How to browse the community wiki

Tags: support

So, some questions are made community wiki, because they cover a broad topic or are not a simple, single answer type question, or have had lots of edits, or whatever. In any case, they will be interesting reading material. So far, I've only come across them by accident. I've tried to find community wiki questions with the search, but failed. There is no tag, and searching for "community wiki" does not get there either. How can I browse the community wiki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ways of the warrior mysterious are. The secret ninja tags use you must.

The mantra **wiki:yes** produce only wiki results will. With **is:question** use it you may to only search questions.

Basically, to be clearer:

> wiki:yes is:question

Will only produce wiki results, and the "is question" tag will filter the post to only show questions. That way you will only see wiki questions.

PS: you will find a list of almost any ninja search tips on the advanced search help section. No all tags are included but most are. Please refer to the free hand circle in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Gee, whiz. Much obliged. Plus one'd.

Comment: My pleasure. Actually, I was looking at that list of search tips just before, searching for the post date filters.  It would seem that they aren't still documented on that page.

Comment: +1 for free-hand circle in the screenshot

Comment: @KitMenke [It works!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/171199)